# I need to create a list that has both colums 1 and 2 equal

Tags: java, list, collections

I need to create a list that has both colums 1 and 2 equal

```
  public static List<Integer> lessThanZero(List<Integer> l) {
        for(int x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
            if(list[x] < 0){

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean *exactly*? Please describe exactly what you were expecting it to do and what it did do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am expecting it to mutate a list by removing all ints that are less than 0

Comment: That's not what you asked initially. Also, what does the test `list[x] < 0` -- never mind the illegal syntax -- have to do with "columns 1 and 2 equal"? What are columns 1 and 2? Finally, if you're mutating a list, why return a list? What's the relationship between the return value and the mutated list?

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: The question has been heavily edited, to the point that it is now a completely different question. This answer is for the original question. The edited question makes no sense to me at this point, so I have not modified this answer to address the edited version.

This should do it:

```
public static List<Integer> lessThanZero(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer val : list) {
        if (val < 0) {
            result.add(val);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or, as of Java 8, you can do it with streams:

```
public static List<Integer> lessThanZero(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().filter(v -> v < 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8+, you might use a `Stream`, a `filter` and a `Collector`. Like,

```
public static List<Integer> lessThanZero(List<Integer> l) {
    return l.stream().filter(x -> x < 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In earlier versions, your current approach will work - but you'll need something to hold the values as you collect them (and I would prefer a `for-each` loop, and it's worth noting that a `List` is not an array)

```
public static List<Integer> lessThanZero(List<Integer> l) {
    List<Integer> r = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer v : l) {
        if (v < 0) {
            r.add(v);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps.

```
public static List<Integer> lessThanZero(List<Integer> list) {

        List<Integer> lessthanlist = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
              if(list[x] < 0){
                   lessthanlist.add(list[x]);
              }
        }

           return lessthanlist;
}
```

Comment: What about for the mutation portion?